# Wait till file is no longer nonexistant perl

Tags: perl

This one is stumping me at the moment so I am reaching out to the best coding community I know of for help after these many long hours and to much coffee.

Basically I need a perl script to wait for files to no longer be present on a server before proceeding. Really looking at waiting for all screen sessions to be terminated (/var/run/screen to be an empty directory).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $directory="/root/screens";

opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
my @files = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

foreach (@files){

        while (-e $_) {
        print "$directory has $_ existing\n";
        sleep 1;
        }
}
```

Ex Dir.

```
  total 8 
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Oct 11 22:58 ./ 
  drwxr-x---. 17 root root 4096 Oct 11 05:33 ../
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root    0 Oct 11 22:58 S-root
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root    0 Oct 11 22:58 S-root1
```

The above does not work obviously, but I am just not seeing a good way to do this on Google and it has been a long day.

Comment: you need a dollar sign in DIR ($DIR)

Comment: No, you don't need a dollar sign in DIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $directory="./test";

my $no_empty = 1;
my @files = ();
while( $no_empty) {
    opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
    @files = readdir DIR;
    #print @files;
    if(scalar @files == 2) {
        $no_empty = 0;
        last;   ##directory is empty
    } else {
        print "Below files present--";
        @files = grep {$_ !~ /\.{1,2}$/} @files;  ## skip . (current dir) and parent dir (..)
        print join (', ',@files);  ##comma seperated file list
        print "\n";   ##mendetory to flash the output buffer
        sleep 1;
    }
}

print "Start with processing cz dir is empty"
```

A sample run --

```
> Below files present--def, abc 
> Below files present--def, abc 
> Below files present--def, abc 
> Below files present--def, abc 
> Start with processing cz dir is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a `while` loop to execute as long as the directory is not empty. Once your target directory is empty the program will return.

Let's create a sub-routine to check if the target directory is empty or not:

```
sub isDirEmpty {
        my ($dir) = @_;
        my $file;
        if (opendir my $DFH, $dir) {
                while ( defined ( $file = readdir $DFH) ) {
                        next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';
                        closedir $DFH;
                        return 0; #Not Empty
                }
                closedir $DFH;
                return 1; #Empty
        } else {
                return -1; #Doesn't exist
        }
}
```

a small test with the infinite loop:

```
my $targetDir = "/path/to/target/dir";
while (1) {
        my $result = isDirEmpty($targetDir);
        if ($result eq 1) {
                print "Your directory is empty\n";
                last;
        } elsif ($result eq -1) {
                print "There has been an error! please check your lousy code!\n";
        }
}
```

Voilà!

Comment: Valid, but I was looking for a solution that had the fewest lines possible as it is part of a rather large script already. I choose the answer posted by virus due to this.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my $directory="/root/screens";
while(<$directory/*>) {
    say "not empty";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: The above will only iterate once for each file within the directory. I  initially was looking to use a glob(ed) wildcard myself, but did not have much luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $directory = "/root/screens";

while(1) {
    my @files = <$directory/*>;
    if($#files == -1) {
        last;
    } else {
        sleep 1;
    }
}

# do some stuff when the directory is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $directory="/root/screens";

opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
@files = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

while (@files > 2) ### If @files have more than 2 items. 
{
opendir(DIR, $directory) or die "couldn't open $directory: $!\n";
@files = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;
sleep (1);
}

print "Directory is now empty and loop has ended";
```

Note that @files will always have 2 items because there will always be ./ and ../